# iscroll4 unexpected behaviour in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, scrollto, iscroll4

I am using iscroll 4 from http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4 and this is working good for me but i am facing one unusual behaviour. I have set up the demo in http://jsfiddle.net/f6vbm/ . Please check in both chrome and firefox. The mouse move is working smooth in chrome but not in firefox. I am using Firefox 8.0.1 . I am not understanding this unexpected result. Please suggest why the scroll and output is not correct in firefox whereas click event is working good. Center item number should be displayed on the header "First Item:"